# Why is chaos a common property of thermal systems?

Tags: thermodynamics, chaos-theory, holographic-principle, thermal-field-theory

https://arxiv.org/abs/1811.06949 pg 3 mentions that chaos is a common property of thermal systems. Can someone please explain why that is?

While looking at [1], I found that indeed most examples were that of thermal systems, however, I did not find any mention of why chaos is common in these systems.

[1] M. Cencini, F. Cecconi and A. Vulpiani, “Chaos: From Simple Models to Complex Systems,” World Scientific: Singapore, 2009

Comment: It's barely tangential to the question, but notice that the book you mention does not cover quantum chaos.

Answer (score 3):

Chaos is common property of systems in general, not only thermal ones - in order to avoid chaos, you need to pick a system by hand, with a simple enough Hamiltonian, which you can't for the typical "thermal system".

In thermodynamics, though, the connection is deeper: thermal systems (in equilibrium) "can be thought of as 'moving through phase space' *ergodically*" [[1](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/269926/75633)], by which one often means *chaotically*: chaos can be considered a form of "strong ergodicity" (for details see this [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/365066/75633) describing  the ergodic hierarchy and, for even more resources on Statistical Mechanics & Dynamical Systems, you can check [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/461138/75633)).